# aws s3 ls filter storage class(STANDARD)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

How to list files but I want to list all standard class only.

I want to exclude glacier class.

Currently here is my command:

```
aws s3 ls s3://Videos/Action/ --human-readable --summarize
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `aws s3 ls` command doesn't display the Storage Class, but you can do it with this command:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket Videos --prefix Action --query "Contents[?StorageClass=='STANDARD'].Key" --output text
```

The output is tab-separated, so you may have to massage the output to get it in your desired format, eg:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket Videos --prefix Action --query "Contents[?StorageClass=='STANDARD'].Key" --output text | sed 's/\t/\n/g'
```

To gain an understanding of how to selectively use the `--query` command, see:

- [How to Filter the Output with the --query Option](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html#controlling-output-filter)
- [JMESPath Tutorial](http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Worked for me, though I had to remove ` --prefix Action`.

Comment: --prefix Action is for folder /Action, I got confused here too.

Comment: Initially it did not work for me (CLI v2 on Linux Fedora). To make it working I had to do the following modifications:
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket Videos --prefix Action --query 'Contents[?StorageClass==\`STANDARD\`].Key' --output text